# append list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to append a list of lists with Python but there is an error. My problem is just with append function. I explain my problem better. I am using a loop. The first time the append function works fine. But for the second time, the function does not work.

When we do the first loop, we get the right result:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2  = [4,5,6]
list3 = []
list3.append(list1)
list3.append(list2)
print(list3)
```

result:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

With the second loop, append does not work correctly. One extra bracket.

```
liste4 = []
liste4.append(list3)
liste4.append(list1)
print(liste4)
```

result:

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [1, 2, 3]]
```

But the result I want is this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Lucy! Take a look at this page please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example    - in your code it is hard to determine what is contained in the parameter data and counter. Can you adapt your code to give an example of the method call so we can execute the code ourselves?

Comment: I updated my question. My problem is just with append. Append makes lists of lists of lists. So that I just need a list of lists.

Comment: Your error might be outside of the give code. With the parameters `counter = 0` and 
`data = [1,1,1,1]` you just write to a file and `self.result` is `[[1,1,1,1]]`. If you call the function again with `counter = 1` and `data=[0,0,0,0]`, then `self.result` will be `[[1,1,1,1], [0,0,0,0]]` which looks like what you want. That is if you haven't altered `self.result`in between somewhere else. It's hard to tell based on the given code excerpt.I suggest removing as much other functionality as possible and using print() statements to figure out where you deviate from what you planned to do.

Comment: My error is just in append. When I add, I have this [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]] while I want this [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just do `list3 = [list1, list2]`

If you want it in a function, here is a go a a List of List creator, which may take multiple lists as the input:

```
def LoL(*lists):
    out = [x for x in lists]
    return out

list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]
list3 = [7,8,9]

list4 = LoL(list1,list2,list3)
list4
>>> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is the iterations. I actually want to iterate, and with each iteration, the value of list2 changes. So with this solution, how do we take into account the old and the new value of list2.

Comment: If you have another problem please update your original post with additional information and data/code.

Comment: It's the same problem

Comment: How is that the same problem?

If you look at the content of list3 you will see: `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]`, which is what you ask how to obtain in your original post.

Comment: I updated my question. I'm sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

Define list3 as an empty list and append to it :

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2  = [4,5,6]
list3 = []
list3.append(list1)
list3.append(list2)
print(list3)
```

Output :

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: I did not validate your answer, but I upvote to thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2  = [4,5,6]
list3 = []
list3.append(list1)
list3.append(list2)
print(list3)
```

result:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

With the second loop:

```
liste4 = list3
liste4.append(list1)
print(liste4)
```

result:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: This solution has already been proposed, I have already said that it does not work.

Comment: It does work, but now I've changed it to mirror your (new) question

Comment: You have understood the problem correctly. We are getting closer to the solution. Now, how do you do in a loop? You cannot use two functions in a single loop.

Comment: I ask you again to please post the full extent of your problem, it makes helping so much easier.

Comment: I did not validate this answer, but I vote to thank you for your help.